# Getting Illegal argument exception while inflating customLayout for an alert dialog using activity

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

I am trying to inflate a custom layout in my alert dialog which is giving me a weird exception.

Code in activity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.blank);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.show();
```

**UPDATE**

I found that `context` that i get is not an activity its alertdialog so it crashes here

`View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_calendar, null);`

How to solve this ?

**Crash Log**

`12-28 23:57:32.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 23:57:32.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17285): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080007 for fragment ScreenSlidePageFragment{417d8500 #0 id=0x7f080007}
12-28 23:57:32.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17285):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:822)
12-28 23:57:32.070: E/AndroidRuntime(17285):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

To:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Comment: Iam using dialog in activity class itself , so i dont think thats useful